# GroupBy and Sum rows using multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to groupby and sum the rows of an Excel file and sum the amount.
Sample Data:

| Name | Age | NetPay | Gross Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Manz | 36 | 260 | 1200 |
| Nerz | 26 | 760 | 1480 |
| Manz | 36 | 140 | 1290 |
| Nerz | 26 | 160 | 1495 |
| Manz | 36 | 880 | 1140 |
| Manz | 16 | 260 | 1200 |
| Kiks | 24 | 470 | 1700 |
| Rats | 31 | 290 | 1760 |
| Manz | 36 | 260 | 1200 |

Expected Output:

| Name | Age | NetPay | Gross Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Manz | 36 | 1540 | 4830 |
| Nerz | 26 | 920 | 2975 |
| Manz | 16 | 260 | 1200 |
| Kiks | 24 | 470 | 1700 |
| Rats | 31 | 290 | 1760 |

```
Sub Output_Final_Validation(strval As String)
    
    Dim wrkbokval As Workbook
    Dim shtval As Worksheet
    Dim shterror As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    
    Set wrkbokval = Workbooks.Open(strval)
    Set shtval = wrkbokPRval.Sheets("Sheet4")
    
    Lastrow = shtval.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    shtval.Range("A2:AP" & Lastrow).Value = shtval.Range("A2:Z" & Lastrow).Value
```

Please suggest how we can resolve it,
I need to groupby on column `Name` and `Age` and ̀ Sum NetPay`and`Gross Value`.
I have tried using Pivot as well but couldn't worked.

Comment: What is the reason not to use a Pivot Table? If `GroupBy` is a must, you could think about an [sql connection](https://skillsandautomation.com/useful-code/use-sql-group-by-in-excel-vba/). It's also possible through formulae, using `SUMIF()`.

Comment: @JvdV  - Sir, Can't use SQL , Need to perform using VBA itself, Please suggest the way to perform in VBA

Comment: @Manz PivotTable will do that even without VBA.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - I have tried using Pivot Table as well but couldn't found any solution, The only Suggestion i have found is using Groupby on the First 2 column and getting the solution

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - Thanks for the Suggestion, But could you help me out with the workaround , How to get over this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a Dictionary to store name concatenaded with age (it looks like it's your unique ID, but consider using something else because 2 people can share name AND age easily) and then apply SumIfs to get your calculus:

```
Sub test()
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim Dict As Object
Dim LR As Long
Dim MyStr As Long

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set rngSource = Range("A2:D" & LR)


For i = 2 To LR Step 1
    If Dict.Exists(Range("A" & i).Value & "|" & Range("B" & i).Value) = False Then
        Dict.Add Range("A" & i).Value & "|" & Range("B" & i).Value, 0
    End If
Next i

'destination. I'm pasting in cell G2

Range("G2").Resize(Dict.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dict.Keys)

Dict.RemoveAll
Set Dict = Nothing

i = 2
Do Until Range("G" & i).Value = ""
    Range("H" & i).Value = Split(Range("G" & i).Value, "|")(1) 'age
    Range("G" & i).Value = Split(Range("G" & i).Value, "|")(0) 'name
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Range("I" & i).Value = .SumIfs(rngSource.Columns(3), rngSource.Columns(1), Range("G" & i).Value, rngSource.Columns(2), Range("H" & i).Value) 'NetPay
        Range("J" & i).Value = .SumIfs(rngSource.Columns(4), rngSource.Columns(1), Range("G" & i).Value, rngSource.Columns(2), Range("H" & i).Value) 'Gross Value
    End With
    i = i + 1
Loop

Set rngSource = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: The Gross value column is not coming as expected. Please Suggest on it

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. How to add up rows if there are multiple column and need to display the output in the new Sheet

Comment: @Manz about bad output i corrected the code because it was summing up always same column (3). About multiple column, I do not understand what you mean. Code something and post where are you stuck or what errors are you getting.